# RTB banners to a landing page on FB, how do i see who converts with a "like"

Tags: facebook-like

If I using a DSP to serve banner ads via RTB and the landing page is my FB ap for a contest, how can i correlate the Clicks and CTR to someone then actually hitting the "like" button on my FB page and ap? Would I need to put the Fb Meta Tab inside of the banner ad?